# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add classes based on when an element reaches the top of the page (-180px for header) but I cannot seem to get the offset top value to work.

I use window load as the size of the images help dictate the height of each section. You can see a live example here http://www.amypreston.co.uk/

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $header = $("header");
    var numberOfSections = $("section").length;   
    var sectionOffsets = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections + 1; i++) {
        sectionOffsets.push($('section').eq(i).offset().top);            
    }            

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();            

        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections + 1; i++) {
            if(scrollTop > sectionOffsets[i] - 180) {
                $header.removeClass().addClass("project" + (i + 1));                         
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try once with removing `+ 1` from `numberOfSections + 1;`

Comment: If you loop until `numberOfSections + 1` then of course you're going to overshoot the array by one.

Comment: Yup above comments are right. You stack Overflow your node list :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `+ 1` from statement

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections + 1; i++) {
```

it should be

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `+1`

**Use this code**

```
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        sectionOffsets.push($('section').eq(i).offset().top);            
    }
```